# Typed Holes in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell

Haskell offers [typed holes](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Holes).

Example:

```
f :: Int -> String -> Bool
f x y = if (x > 10) then True else (g y)

g :: String -> Bool
g s = _
```

Compilation:

```
Prelude> :l HoleEx.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( HoleEx.hs, interpreted )

HoleEx.hs:6:7:
    Found hole `_' with type: Bool
    Relevant bindings include
      s :: String (bound at HoleEx.hs:6:3)
      g :: String -> Bool (bound at HoleEx.hs:6:1)
    In the expression: _
    In an equation for `g': g s = _
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

When programming in Scala, I typically use `???` as placeholders in my Scala code that I've not yet written.

However, using typed holes appears to be more powerful to me. Note that I could replace the above `else (g y)` with `else (g 55)`, yet I'd get a compile-time error:

```
Prelude> :l HoleEx.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( HoleEx.hs, interpreted )

HoleEx.hs:3:39:
    Couldn't match type `Int' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: Int
    In the first argument of `g', namely `x'
    In the expression: (g x)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Although I can use `???` in Scala to get placeholder implementations to compile, unlike holes, I'll get run-time errors with `???`.

```
scala> def g(x: Int): Int = ???
g: (x: Int)Int

scala> g(5)
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

Does Scala have typed holes?

Comment: The compile time error has nothing to do with type holes, it is a normal type mismatch.

Comment: Could you please explain, @sschaef? I don't follow.

Comment: You have a function `g` that expects a `String`. With `g 55` you pass an `Int`, thus the type mismatch.

Answer (score 7):

For me a hole in a program helps me progress the implementation. It does that by telling me what type I need next. You can get something a little like that by triggering a regular Scala type error.

The trick is to define a type you know will be wrong, and then use it.  For example:

```
object hole
```

You can then use that in code and you'll get an appropriate type error:

[image: screen shot of a compiler error when using a hole]

The error here is telling me the "hole" needs to be a `B`, suggesting I can progress by using `g` in some way.  And if I progress the code to `a => f(g(hole))` the compiler will tell me the `hole` needs to be an `A`.

That's a kind of hole, but unlike other languages (Idris etc)...

- my program is just not compiling, rather than having a recognized hole as such;
- there's no help to tell me the types in scope (although IDE code completion my give some suggestions);
- I can't nicely name a hole;
- I can't automatically lift a hole to a function definition;
- I can't automatically solve the hole (as Idris can, sometimes);
- I *must* type the expected return value, otherwise Scala will infer that `hole` is an acceptable type!
- ...and probably many other features.

As you say `???` is a useful placeholder, but it has type `Nothing` -- which means the program compiles, but it doesn't help you fill in the implementation. 
At least `object hole`, although kind of trivial, does give you some type information to progress.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful reply, Richard. I suppose another downside is that I have to `import ...` or define `object hole` wherever I want to use it.

Answer (score 5):

Scala's `???` is just a shorthand for throwing an exception, and is equivalent to Haskell's `undefined` or just `error "not implemented"` or similar.

The Scala compiler does not have support for typed holes. You can however just use `???` and inspect the type of that in an IDE or Emacs+Ensime to see its inferred type.

Scala's type inference is relatively minimal when compared to the full Hindley-Milner type inference of languages like Haskell. Which means that having something like typed holes in the Scala compiler would not be feasible.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Scala compiler plugin by Chris Birchall called [`scala-typed-holes`](https://github.com/cb372/scala-typed-holes) that implements typed holes:

```
package example

object Example {

  def foo(x: Int, y: String): Boolean = {
    if (y.length == x) {
       ??? // TODO implement!
    } else {
     true
   }
} 

def bar(x: Int): String = x match {
    case 0 => "zero"
    case 1 => "one"
    case _ => ???
  }
}
```

Generates:

```
[warn] /Users/chris/code/scala-typed-holes/src/test/scala/example/Example.scala:7:7:
[warn] Found hole with type: Boolean
[warn] Relevant bindings include
[warn]   x: Int (bound at Example.scala:5:11
[warn]   y: String (bound at Example.scala:5:19)
[warn]
[warn]       ??? // TODO implement!
[warn]       ^
[warn] /Users/chris/code/scala-typed-holes/src/test/scala/example/Example.scala:16:15:
[warn] Found hole with type: String
[warn] Relevant bindings include
[warn]   x: Int (bound at Example.scala:13:11)
[warn]
[warn]     case _ => ???
[warn]               ^
```